# Retrieve Base64 from Canvas with filters

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I need to retrieve the Base64 from a Canvas where I have applied some filters with CSS.

I have tried 
 `canvas.toDataURL()`

but it will give Base64 of the original image.

Is there a way to retrieve the Base64 of the image with filters?

Comment: CSS filters are effectively post-processing, they are not part of the image on the canvas. You will need to apply a similar filter yourself (or using a library) to the data on the canvas.

Comment: @DBS So I should apply filters directly to the Base64?

Comment: I would apply it to the canvas itself, before you produce the base64. If your browser supports it, the canvas API has [some standard filters built in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter) Otherwise, perhaps look into libraries that do similar things (Or [write the filters yourself](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/) if you're interested in pixel-level manipulation)

Comment: @DBS Thanks that worked!!
Post the answer so I can give you the points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS filters are not part of the canvas itself, they're applied over the canvas.

To include the filter in the generated image, you need to apply the filter to the canvas itself using JavaScript, to do this you have two main options:

- Use the [built in filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter), which can do pretty much the same thing as CSS filters (However with [limited browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-api_canvasrenderingcontext2d_filter), at the time of writing)
- Write your own filters (Or find a library that does it for you). This one goes a little out of the scope of this question, however there are some [good tutorials](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/) for this sort of thing.